# how to create/debug nested case/conditional sql statments in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a product and producttype table, and working on a query to calculate total to return a item. return price is based on type of the product and whether there is shipping charges or restocking fee in percent. please see the query below so far that i have, ( currently,i'm getting this error ->  ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"
Position: 1050

my understading was , i can have a nested case statments . I am checking the product type, then if shipping charges or restockingpercent is not null, if they are not , i just add that to the total.i don't see anything jumping out with the code that is syntactically wrong, but i'm new to this and may be missing something basic.

```
productType Table
id  | type 
1  | Electronics
2  | Furniture 
...
```

```
product table
id | productName | type | price | shipping charges | restockingPercent
1  | laptop      | 1    | 200   | 20               | 15
...
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, p."price" , t."type" , p."shippingcharges" , p."restockingPercent", 
CASE t."type"
     when "Electronics" then

      CASE WHEN p."shippingcharges" IS NOT NULL AND p."restockingPercent is NOT NULL
        THEN (p.price + p.shippingcharges + ((p.restockingPercent/100)*p.price ) )
      CASE WHEN p."shippingcharges" IS NOT NULL 
        THEN (p.price + p.shippingcharges ) 
      CASE WHEN p."shippingcharges" IS NOT NULL 
        THEN (p.price + ((p.restockingPercent/100)*p.price ) ) 
      ELSE p.price 
      END
        AS totalPrice
    when "Furniture"
       ....

end product_return_calculation
FROM "Product" p join "ProductType" t ON 
p."typeId" = t.id ;
```

Comment: Did you close every case using END?

Comment: @FrankHeikens - yes

Comment: Show me. The message is about Position: 1050 and you show us the first hundred or so characters. How do you think we can find the bug in the missing part when we don't have it? By the way, deep nested conditions are a bad design, in any programming language. Advice: Try to avoid it, you already found out why.

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
CASE 
     WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
     WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
     …
     ELSE result_e
END
```

not

```
CASE WHEN condition_1 THEN result_1
CASE WHEN condition_2 THEN result_2
…
ELSE result_e
END
```